# filterAll(); not working with leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, dc.js, crossfilter, dc.leaflet.js

I'm trying to reset a leaflet map (to its original view) after clicking on a marker using:

```
<h5>Location <a class="reset" href="javascript:mapLocation.filterAll(); dc.redrawAll();">reset</a></h5>
```

Where mapLocation is my leaflet map variable. I'm using dc.leaflet.js to link a map and datatable together. I'm driving the datatable content from the leaflet map. So when the map is reset all of the items should show in the table again.

Starting view:
[image: Map starting view]

Map after clicking bubble #4:
[image: Map after clicking on #4 bubble]

Then clicking on reset does not return it to it's original view.

Here is a similar use of reset with with the same problem: http://bl.ocks.org/Mbrownshoes/679a255540eb11d16704c44d88314075

Here is my [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Vy3bsFUUEMNlQlLtZ9L)

Just modified my code from:

```
<h5>Location <a class="reset" href="javascript:mapLocation.filterAll(); redrawAll();">reset</a></h5>
```

To this:

```
<h5>Location <a class="reset" href="javascript:location.reload();">reset</a></h5>
```

That indeed refreshes the page as such resets the dc.filter, is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Looks like reset works okay in that example; the problem is that France turns purple and stays that way the first time it is clicked. Is that the same problem, and are you also using the choropleth? The different dc.leaflet charts are implemented differently.

Comment: I am not using a chloropleth, I am using the bubble chart option of dc.leaflet.js: https://plnkr.co/edit/1Vy3bsFUUEMNlQlLtZ9L when I refresh the browser the leaflet map reset to it's original view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using:

```
<h5>Location <a class="reset" href="javascript:location.reload();">reset</a></h5>
```

To reload the whole page.

Alternatively this also worked, swapped var mapLocation with window.mapLocation

```
 window.mapLocation = dc.leafletMarkerChart("#location", groupname)
```